# How can I use groupby to merge rows in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

| ID | Name | Major1 | Major2 | Major3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | Dave | English | NaN | NaN |
| 12 | Dave | NaN | Biology | NaN |
| 12 | Dave | NaN | NaN | History |
| 13 | Nate | Spanish | NaN | NaN |
| 13 | Nate | NaN | Business | NaN |

I need to merge rows resulting in this:

| ID | Name | Major1 | Major2 | Major3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | Dave | English | Biology | History |
| 13 | Nate | Spanish | Business | NaN |

I know this is possible with groupby but I haven't been able to get it to work correctly. Can anyone help?

Comment: post some code so others can help you with it

Answer (score 0):

If you are intent on using groupby, you could do something like this:

```
dataframe = dataframe.melt(['ID', 'Name']).dropna()

dataframe = dataframe.groupby(['ID', 'Name', 'variable'])['value'].sum().unstack('variable')
```

You may have to mess with the column names a bit, but this is what comes to me as a possible solution using groupby.

Answer (score -1):

Use `melt` and `pivot`

```
>>> df.melt(['ID', 'Name']).dropna() \
      .pivot(['ID', 'Name'], 'variable', 'value') \
      .reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)

   ID  Name   Major1    Major2   Major3
0  12  Dave  English   Biology  History
1  13  Nate  Spanish  Business      NaN
```